# Convert protobuf to struct in golang

Tags: go, struct, type-conversion, protocol-buffers

I want to convert the proto Message to struct. Definitions of proto Message and struct:

```
ProtoMessage:
message Person {
  string Name = 1;
  int64 Age = 2;
  string Location = 3;
}

Human Struct:
type human struct {
    Name     string `protobuf:"Name"`
    Age      int64  `protobuf:"Age"`
    Location string `protobuf:"Location"`
}
```

Right now I see that the only option is to convert proto to JSON and JSON to struct using protojson and json library. Can someone recommend any other way of conversion?

Comment: Do you really need conversion from protobuf file to struct? Can you use protoc to generate struct from protobuf file and use that instead?

Comment: I think you are mixing two concepts here, and this is probably the problem. Protobufs are ultimately DTOs - a contract, if you wish. Using them as native entities only leads to blood, sweat and tears. Tested for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

The protobuf compiler should effectively do this for you.

From scratch, do this prep (the `75705541` number is this present stackoverflow question):

```bash
$ mkdir 75705541
$ cd 75705541
$ wget https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v22.2/protoc-22.2-linux-x86_64.zip
$ unzip protoc-22.2-linux-x86_64.zip
$ PATH="$(pwd)/bin:${PATH}"
$ go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@latest
```

Create a local file (`ex.proto`):

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

message Person {
  string Name = 1;
  int64 Age = 2;
  string Location = 3;
}
```

Then *compile it* to Go:

```
$ protoc -I=./ --go_out=./ --go_opt=Mex.proto=this/ex ex.proto
```

The generated output, `this/ex/ex.pb.go` contains this definition for `Person`:

```golang
type Person struct {
        state         protoimpl.MessageState
        sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
        unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

        Name     string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=Name,proto3" json:"Name,omitempty"`
        Age      int64  `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=Age,proto3" json:"Age,omitempty"`
        Location string `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=Location,proto3" json:"Location,omitempty"`
}
```

which is almost what you want. It has some extra fields, but these are private so they won't be visible outside our generated `"this/ex"` package.

Converting from a wire format blob to this structure uses [code like this](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Unmarshal):

```golang
        var data []byte = yourData // the binary blob of wire format data
        var person ex.Person
        if err := proto.Unmarshal(data, &person); err != nil {
                // handle decode problem, see err.
                return err
        }
        // person now holds the data you want.
```

If you must have a simple version, you will likely have to hand edit one. You could start with something like this:

```bash
$ cat this/ex/ex.pb.go | sed -n '/^type Person struct {/,/^}/p' | sed -e '/^[\t]\+[a-z].*$/d'
```

but you will need to write a function to import this by copying each of the exported fields from `this/ex.Person` to your `Person` definition. This is relatively easy for a simple type like `ex.Person`, but it will get complicated if you have a nested protobuf definition.