# Cannot import proto file in Golang project

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

`import "filter.proto"; Import "filter.proto" was not found or had errors.`

I cannot to do this. I dont relize how to add --protoc_path to my dir. Its app will be in docker.

i use vs code

its my another file (filter.proto):

`syntax = "proto3";`

`package common.filter.v1;`

`option go_package = "github.com/../../server/gen/go/common/filter/v1;pb_common_filter";`

`message Pagination {   uint64 limit = 1;   uint64 offset = 2; }`

my dirs:

proto
-common
-filter
-v1
filter.proto
-service
-products
-v1
-service.proto

its all in the folder (server)

i tried rename path in import, but i nothing

Comment: Please take your time to express yourself better in your question. Make sure to format your question, look at the preview.

Answer (score 1):

You can't import a protobuf definition because it isn't a valid Go package. You have to compile the protobuf into Go code. Google "protobuf to golang struct". This SO question has a reasonably good answer: [Convert protobuf to struct in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75705541/convert-protobuf-to-struct-in-golang). Obviously you should also read the official protobuf documentation. I recommend starting with the tutorial: https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/gotutorial/.

Comment: it still doesnt work. 'protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable'